# How to get client ip from webseal?

Tags: webseal

I'm new to IBM ISAM and webseal.

How do backend applications get the client (user browser end) ip address?
I am able to retrieve the ip address from the HTTP request but that's the address of the reverse proxy and not the client.

The traffic goes from:
Client > load balancer > reverse proxy > backend app

Comment: Front-end load balancer should pass visitor's IP address, usually by `HTTP_X_FORWARDED_FOR` header.

Comment: I've added the header but it gives me the IP of the load balancer not the client.

Comment: @happymeal this is the expected behavior. Please refer to the following: https://www.ibm.com/support/pages/client-ip-address-missing-x-forwarded-header

Answer (score 0):

Use the [header-names] stanza of the reverse proxy config file and add an entry like the following:

client-ip-v4 = YourHeaderName

The value will be passed in the header named "YourHeaderName". You can rename YourHeaderName to whatever you want.

It's documented here: https://www.ibm.com/support/knowledgecenter/SSPREK_9.0.1/com.ibm.isam.doc/wrp_stza_ref/reference/ref_srvr_name.html